# Floor strength help

Tags: floor

We have a second story floor 12 ft long 2x12 16 on center. We want to put a 36 x 80 piece of equipment that's 400 lbs that vibrates. Looking for load specifically. Do we need to double 2x12 under the unit.

Comment: 400 lbs isn't that heavy... 16" OC is pretty beefy... the issue isn't the load it is how bad the vibrations are and what they actually do.   So for anyone to answer this they will need to know the specs on the machine that is vibrating.

Comment: @DMoore Vibration does not add to or take away from the strength of floor joists. Why do you think it does?

Comment: Have 3 friends stand close together and jump up and down that would simulate the machine I don’t think that’s very heavy for that large of an area.

Answer (score 3):

Each 2x12 spanning 12’ will support about 2250 lbs. depending on the species and grade of the joists.

So, total load is not an issue, but the strength of the subfloor and shear walls around this object could be a problem.

I’d check the subfloor and where the posts (if any) rests between the joists.

Comment: Not sure why the down vote reversed.

Comment: @EdBeal I have a lot of answers downvoted. Not sure why, because I try to give code references or calculations with my answers. A couple of days ago I had 4 downvotes within 2 hours of posting my answer. That has to be a record on SE.

Comment: I have for years gotten down votes with no comment so I reverse most of them if there is no comment. But I agree that was a small load for that many square feet. Nope have had more when it was a simple 2 line straight code answer and a joke about my answer got more upvotes. My opinion is they come from people that really have not built anything but try to be internet carpenter and electricians.

Comment: Thanks for  all the help. The 3 friends is a great example of the vibration

Comment: @Rjsugar I’m not worried about holding this item up, I’m more worried about 1) the subfloor spanning from joist to joists is suitable, and 2) if the vibration (and shaking) could cause the room to rotate and shear the walls.

Comment: More info needed about the frequency and coupling energy of the vibrations in relation to the possible resonant frequencies of the structure. Remember the Tacoma Narrows bridge failure.

Comment: If it has feet, set them on isolation pads. If it's flat bottomed, set it on an isolation mat. Or a foam sheet... But the load is only 20 psf.

Comment: I've received a number of them too, with no comments... @Ed Beal  has reversed many, I've learned from his example.

Comment: Rjsugar, if you find an answer or comment helpful upvote or accept it the check mark, this helps others find the question in the future and also brings your question to the top of the stack where it might get more comments and answers. But there is some good info her.